# C Programming: How to determine an exact match between 2 numbers

Tags: c, arrays, matching

I am trying to find the exact match between two numbers and have my counter stop at the first instance when they are not a match. However the code I have written counts the entire string length of my numbers.  Is there an alternative way to do this?

Since my counter is starting from the first decimal place and not 0. , it counts to 15 but should stop at 10.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){    
    char str[100];
    char buf[100];

    double l,m,a,b;

    int c,d,t,u,r,q;
    int count =0;

    l=59874.141715197809000;
    m=59874.141715197817000;

    a= (l - (int)l);
    b= (m -(int)m);

    sprintf(str,"%.15f",a);
    sprintf(buf,"%.15f",b);

    c = strlen(str);
    d = strlen(buf);

    for(t=3;t<c;t++){
        for(u=3;u<d;u++){
            if(str[t]==buf[u]){
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("matching decimal places = %d \n",count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sprintf(str, %.15f",a);` but a is an integer.. and you're missing a quote there..

Comment: And you don't need 2 loops.

Comment: And `a= (l - (int)l)` is always zero here.

Comment: @J...S that is a lower case L not a 1, I subtracted the integer part from the decimal part

Comment: @J...S. yes, when `a` is an `int`. But not if a `float`

Comment: @J...S sorry I retyped my code, a and b are both doubles in my compiler

Comment: Your code is hard to read for me.. https://ideone.com/yiY1op . In any case, you only need one loop and it starts at 2 because decimals start with 0 + decimal point. Not sure why your loop started at 3..

Comment: @Brandon I apologize for that, this is an excerpt from a larger piece of code I wrote and retyped everything piece by piece.  Why would I only need one loop?

Comment: Well.. you only need one loop because you only need to iterate the length of the smallest string. Since that's the case, one loop will suffice. You iterate the length of the smallest string while comparing the characters in that string with the next one.

Comment: You probably meant the commas in `for(t=3,t<c,t++){
` to be semicolons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when comparing two strings, you only need to iterate to the length of the smallest string if the two strings differ in length.. That is, if you want to count the amount of sequential character matches in a string.

For example:

```
A = 0.99997552
B = 0.9999753
```

would need one for loop to compare.. You would only iterate up to the length of B to determine that 6 decimals match. Why? Because going any further is irrelevant since none of the extra digits would exist in B. Iterating past the end of an array is undefined behaviour anyway.

In your case both buffers are the same length so no worries there, but again, the shorter string won't have the extra digits found in the longer string.. Hence: Iterate up to the smallest length.

The solution can be done as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    //Create large enough buffer to hold 100 digits/characters..
    char str[100] = {0};
    char buf[100] = {0};

    //Two doubles to be compared..
    double l = 59874.141715197809000;
    double m = 59874.141715197817000;

    //Counter keeps track of matching digits..
    int count = 0;

    //Get rid of the base and keep only the decimals..
    double a = (l - (int)l);
    double b = (m - (int)m);

    //Copy a maximum of 15 decimal places to `str` and `buf`
    sprintf(str, "%.15f", a);
    sprintf(buf,"%.15f", b);

    //Get the length of both strings..
    int c = strlen(str);
    int d = strlen(buf);

    //If C is smaller, iterate to length(c) else iterate to length(d).
    for (int i = 2; i < (c < d ? c : d); ++i)
    {
        //If the two characters match, increment the count..
        if (str[i] == buf[i])
        {
            ++count;
        }
    }

    //Print the amount of matching decimals..
    printf("matching decimal places = %d \n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I had contemplated using a ternary operator earlier but I brushed off the notion when I converted a and b into strings with 15 decimal places.  Thank you very much for your explanation and time!

Comment: @KolacheMaster Here the ternary operator is used to return the min of `c` and `d`.

Comment: @MFisherKDX the ternary operator is returning which string length is smaller, they are both equal therefore due to its syntax it out puts d and then i < d is used as the second expression in the for loop.

Answer (score -1):

This may not be the answer, but do

```
if (number1 == number2)
{
// do something to stop it
}
```

Comment: I think he wants to know the number of matching decimal decimal places.